# TWRP: Failed to mount '/data'

Tags: samsung, rom-flashing, twrp, mount, system-error

When I try to install a ROM with TWRP, I get

```
Could not mount /data and unable to find crypto footer.
Failed to mount '/data' (Invalid argument)
Unable to recreate /data/media folder.
Updating partition details...
Failed to mount '/data' (Invalid argument)
...done
Unable to mount storage
Failed to mount '/data' (Invalid argument)
Full SELinux support is present
Unable to mount /data/media/TWRP/.twrps
```

Then when I try to "Factory Reset" under TWRP Wipe, I get

```
/sbin/e2fsck -fp /dev/block/sda18 process ended with ERROR: 8
Unable to repair Data.
Failed to mount '/data' (Invalid argument)
Error changing file systems
Repairing Data using e2fsck...
```

I am using a Samsung Galaxy S7.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you need to do is remove Crypto on Data

To do that, in TWRP

- Settings
- Format Data
- Type "yes"
- Done

Comment: I go to Settings but there is no Format Data button or option?

Comment: Are you in TWRP?

Comment: yes, version 3.2.1-0

Comment: @Ooker do you see it under `Wipe`? or the like?

Comment: found it, thanks

Comment: It would be a great addition to TWRP if it supported mounting an encrypted partition ...