# How to create filesystem in TWRP? Getting error: "Unable to format to remove encryption"

Tags: rom-flashing, twrp, file-system, encryption, mount

The screen appears after booting into TWRP and trying to format memory:

[image]

I was trying to flash a custom ROM using TWRP recovery but it's showing **Unable to mount storage** & **Failed to mount '/data' (Invalid argument).**

I tried several methods like formatting memory but it's also not happening. It's showing **Unable to format to remove encryption.** Also tried to change the file format but nothing helped me. Now whenever I switch my phone on it automatically boot up into TWRP recovery mode. I tried [this method](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/201709/twrp-failed-to-mount-data) and almost every method possible but nothing helped.

I'm using **Moto E4 Plus** (*nicklaus*).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same problem, and what worked for me, I formatted it from command line, so while in fastboot mode I typed:

```
fastboot format userdata
```

Then I flashed TWRP and rebooted into it and the files in the storage were all showing, all was working.

Answer (score 3):

You can always format from command-line to be sure where the problem is (if any). **This will erase your whole `/data` partition** which contains personal data, apps etc.

- Boot to TWRP recovery.
- Find block device for `userdata` partition. Usually it's symlinked at `/dev/block/by-name/userdata` or `/dev/block/bootdevice/by-name/userdata`. See **FINDING BLOCK DEVICE** section in [this answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/208114/218526).
- Make sure `userdata` partition is not mounted (which already seems the case here). Execute `mount` to see all mounted filesystems. To un-mount open terminal or `adb shell` and execute:

  ```
  ~# umount /data
  ~# umount /sdcard
  ```
- Find partition size:

  ```
  ~# SIZE=$(blockdev --getsz /dev/block/by-name/userdata)
  ```

  You get size in 512-byte sectors.
- Leave (at least) [16 KB](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/vold/+/refs/tags/android-9.0.0_r1/cryptfs.cpp#465) (32 sectors) at partition end for crypto footer - it's required on devices using Full Disk Encryption ([FDE](https://source.android.com/security/encryption/full-disk)):

  ```
  ~# SIZE=$((SIZE - 32))
  ```
- Create filesystem on the rest of space. To create `f2fs` filesystem:

  ```
  ~# mkfs.f2fs -l data /dev/block/by-name/userdata $SIZE
  ```

  To create `ext4` filesystem, size is to be provided in block count. If using 4KB block size:

  ```
  ~# mkfs.ext4 -L data -b 4096 /dev/block/by-name/userdata $((SIZE * 512 / 4096))
  ```

  Or if older [Android-specific](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/extras/+/3f6ea671d55b0f8ba9bab8826c817327d67ee9bb) `make_ext4fs` is available:

  ```
  ~# make_ext4fs -L data -l $((SIZE * 512)) /dev/block/by-name/userdata
  ```

  `data` is filesystem/volume label.

---

**NOTES:**

- `blockdev` and `mkfs.*`/`make_ext4fs` are usually bundled with TWRP or you need to get static binaries.
- Why we need to leave space for crypto-footer? See quote from [Partition map](https://source.android.com/devices/tech/ota/nonab/device_code#partition-map):

  > Starting in Android 3.0, the `recovery.fstab` file gains an additional optional field, *options*. Currently the only defined option is *length* , which lets you explicitly specify the length of the partition. This length is used when reformatting the partition (e.g., for the `userdata` partition during a data wipe/factory reset operation, or for the `system` partition during installation of a full OTA package). If the `length` value is negative, then the size to format is taken by adding the length value to the true partition size. For instance, setting `"length=-16384"` means the last 16k of that partition will not be overwritten when that partition is reformatted. This supports features such as encryption of the `userdata` partition (where encryption metadata is stored at the end of the partition that should not be overwritten).
- You don't need to provide filesystem size if you don't intend to encrypt your device or if device uses File Based Encryption ([FBE](https://source.android.com/security/encryption/file-based)). To create filesystem on whole partition:

  ```
  ~# mkfs.f2fs -l data /dev/block/by-name/userdata
  ```