# Unable to flash custom ROM using TWRP, successfully installing AOSP extended, rebooting the device. Upon reboot it boots to TWRP instead of ROM

Tags: rom-flashing, custom-roms, twrp, file-system, aosp

Successfully installed the AOSP Extended image for 'nicklaus'. Whenever I reboot my device to boot my device, instead of booting to  the custom ROM my device automatically boot itself into TWRP recovery, as if like there is no ROM installed at all.

[image: TWRP screenshot]

I'm trying to flash AOSP extended or any other custom ROM to my device ('nicklaus' Motorola E4 Plus). After wiping the internal storage (dalvik & cache) and then successfully install the custom ROM.

**Actually I flashed .zip file, GApps, and then reboot the device, the device automatically boot itself into TWRP recovery mode. Previously, I fixed my [file system problem](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/220599/how-to-create-filesystem-in-twrp-getting-error-unable-to-format-to-remove-enc) and then tried multiple times to install compatible ROMs. However, nothing helped at all.**

After uninstalling stock ROM. I actually flashed ViperOS,
Lineage, Remix OS and AOSP extended as well. But after fixing the file
system issue nothing helped me to flash any ROMs.

Comment: custom rom needs working full stock rom as base

Comment: Can't get it. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: install working stock rom. when phone is in good condition, wipe only system and format data before flashing custom rom. don't wipe vendor modem etc because it's not included in custom rom. don't flash gapps

Comment: No I also tried to flash the stock ROM but it's also not working at all.

Comment: you need firmware for exact model. E4+ comes with different chipsets Qualcomm or Mediatek. watch youtube how to flash stock rom

Comment: just to be clear, full stock ROM means all partitions including stock recovery. unmodified stock ROM won't boot along with TWRP (flash it together with modified vbmeta/dtbo after phone is working again)

Comment: I flashed full stock ROM recently but my phone's problem isn't solved totally bTW. Now my SIM cards are not working and fingerprint gestures aren't working and don't even mentioned in the moto's dedicated app. Also unable to flash TWRP recovery.

Comment: maybe the "fixed file system problem" has overwritten important partition which is not included in stock ROM

Comment: So what I have to do now to resolve this network related issue?

Comment: if device is on stock rom but factory reset does not fix it, you have serious issue. we don't know the history what you have done so far. open thread on xda or ask in lenovo forum, this cannot be answered as Q&A