# How to create filesystem in TWRP? Getting error: Unable to recreate /data/media folder. E: Cannot decrypt adopted storage because /data will not mount

Tags: twrp, file-system, xiaomi, mount, adoptable-storage

I tried to flash custom ROM on my Xiaomi Poco M2 Pro (gram) without putting too much thought and then something happened and now it's saying these on every recovery.

```
Failed to mount '/data' (Invalid argument)
Unable to recreate /data/media folder.
E: Cannot decrypt adopted storage because /data will not mount
Updating partition details...
...done
Unable to mount storage
Full SELinux support is present.
Unable to mount /data/media/TWRP/.twrps
Unable to mount /data/media/TWRP/.twrps
```

<sup>[Original screenshot of the TWRP output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DdtIy.jpg)</sup>

Tried to flash stock firmware using Mi Flash Tool but it just gives me errors: "Writing /userdata, partition not found" and on TWRP

> Failed to mount '/data' (Invalid argument)
> Unable to recreate /data/media folder.
> E: Cannot decrypt adopted storage because /data will not mount

I've tried almost everything to fix this phone but failed.
I've tried [this](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/220599/how-to-create-filesystem-in-twrp-getting-error-unable-to-format-to-remove-enc?newreg=c71f051349f94f4f9621ea27f8335c22) solution too but didn't work

Hope someone would give me a solution to this problem.

Comment: execute `flash_all_except_storage.bat` from fastboot (make sure the directory path does not contain whitespaces)